# grub2 issues with RHEL/CentOS 8.7 installed on GPT disks and Legacy BIOS

Tags: centos, grub2, lvm

I am trying to install CentOS 8.7 (I understand it's been EOL'd, I've also tried it with AlmaLinux) on two 4TB disks where `/boot` partition is an mdadm RAID1 partition and all the other partitions (/, /var, /home, etc.) are in LVM raid1.

The basic structure is similar to this which I have running on a different server that I believe have been installed with CentOS 8.2 with the anaconda gui installer with no issues (which makes me think maybe I should try installing centos 8.2 and updating it to 8.7?)

```
# For the purposes of showing raid1/lvm setup as an example:
[root@server /]# lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0    1G  0 part
│ └─md127               9:127  0 1023M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda2                  8:2    0  1.8T  0 part
  └─md126               9:126  0  1.8T  0 raid1
    ├─srv-root    253:0    0   20G  0 lvm   /
    ├─srv-swap    253:1    0    8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─srv-usr     253:2    0   30G  0 lvm   /usr
    ├─srv-var     253:3    0   50G  0 lvm   /var
    ├─srv-tmp     253:4    0    4G  0 lvm   /tmp
    ├─srv-var_log 253:5    0    5G  0 lvm   /var/log
    └─srv-home    253:6    0  1.7T  0 lvm   /home
sdb                     8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1                  8:17   0    1G  0 part
│ └─md127               9:127  0 1023M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb2                  8:18   0  1.8T  0 part
  └─md126               9:126  0  1.8T  0 raid1
    ├─srv-root    253:0    0   20G  0 lvm   /
    ├─srv-swap    253:1    0    8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─srv-usr     253:2    0   30G  0 lvm   /usr
    ├─srv-var     253:3    0   50G  0 lvm   /var
    ├─srv-tmp     253:4    0    4G  0 lvm   /tmp
    ├─srv-var_log 253:5    0    5G  0 lvm   /var/log
    └─srv-home    253:6    0  1.7T  0 lvm   /home
```

Edit: the above is just an example of the disk layout I am trying to setup on a new server which I was successfully able to setup a year or two ago on a different server.  This does not show the bios_grub partition but I do have this created on this "new" server.

Fast forward to trying to setup a new server with AlmaLinux/CentOS 8.7, the installer fails to install the bootloader.  So I uncheck the "install bootloader" option and once the installer finishes, I switch to a shell mount all the system paths like `/proc`, `/dev`, etc. Then chroot to `/mnt/sysimage` before running installing grub and mkconfig like:

```
grub2-install /dev/sda
grub2-install /dev/sdb
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Then reboot.  I can get grub menu to load but when I try to boot, I see a bunch of dracut-initqueue timeouts before ending with:

Error when booting with grub:

```
Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
...
Warning: could not boot.
Warning: /dev/mapper/srv-root does not exist
```

The error is very clear, that it can't find the root partition but after three nights of troubleshooting, I cannot figure out why.

All the installing and troubleshooting is done via a KVM/IP setup by my datacenter but I do not have unlimited time with it.  Would like to get some ideas from others here that can provide any advice before I request access to the KVM again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not know Redhat, but grub in BIOS mode requires a bios_grub partition if drive is gpt partitioned. The bios_grub can be 1 or 2MB and must be unformatted. It needs bios_grub flag if using gparted or ef02 if using gdisk.

Comment: @oldfred thanks for the comment.  Forgot to mention that both disks have a 1MB partition with bios_grub flag.  To confirm though, doesn't the fact that the grub menu loads confirm that this is not the issue?  Was thinking that if the issue is with the bios_grub partition then the grub menu wouldn't even load.

Comment: Ok not bios_grub. In Ubuntu there have been several posts on those with /boot inside the LVM. But it seem some update is not including correct parameters. It may be a .mod that has to be in grub.cfg or whatever Redhat uses grub.config?  Also is LVM set up old? Soneone posted this: "Nowadays GRUB (v2.06) allows to boot Linux from a LUKS-encrypted /boot partition (even one inside a LVM) with the GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y key and the appropriate LUKS or LUKS2 modules loaded." So grub may need correct .mod files loaded?